# Bernoulli Trials question involving binomial variables

Tags: probability, bernoulli-numbers

In the exercise, X is a binomial variable with n = 6 and p = 0.2. Compute the given probability.(Round your answer to five decimal places.)

P(X = 5)

For this one I did:

(6C5)((.2)^3)((.8)^3)=.024576 which rounded to 5 decimal places is 0.02458

But this is not the correct answer, could someone tell me how to do this problem correctly or where I went wrong?

Comment: Why did you use $3$s in your $\displaystyle {6 \choose 5}0.2^3\, 0.8^3$?

Comment: Because 3+3 is 6 and in combinations with bernoulli trials aren't the exponents always supposed to add up to the first number in the combination?

Comment: Adding up to $6$ is correct for this question, but $3+3$ is not the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equation would be $P(X=r) = \binom{n}{r}p^r (1-p)^{(n-r)}$.

That gives (6C5)((.2)^5)((.8)^1) = 0.001536

You seem to have both exponents for $p$ and $(1-p)$ as $3$ for some reason.

Comment: Oh, I should have done the opposite formula thing for this question, man thats totally my bad